# Disable Session Lookup for a single controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I want to disable sessions completely for a controller action, because I want *this single controller action* (it's an autocomplete action on thousands of values, so speed matters) to be blazingly fast.

I tried using [session_off](https://github.com/kares/session_off), but it just sets the `session` variable to nil, an still looks up the users session in the database.

Is it possible to completely disable the `Rails::SessionStore` middleware, but only for a single controller action or URL?

I am running `rails 3.2.17`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: handle this endpoint in a Rack middleware of your own, and insert it into the stack as early as possible!

You can achieve this in config/routes.rb just by routing to the middleware object:

`match 'my_autocomplete_endpoint', to: AutocompleteMiddleware`

then just return a response from the middleware and don't go up the stack.

You can put this wherever you want in the stack in config/application.rb with:

`config.middleware.insert_before(SomeOtherMiddleware, AutocompleteMiddleware)`

e.g., perhaps insert it before `Rails::SessionStore`.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5+ solution (maybe before, not sure when this became available).

Add this to your controller.  You can specify which actions should not touch/update the session using the `only:` option.

```
after_action -> { request.session_options[:skip] = true }, only: :my_action_name
```

This will make the response not include the `set_cookie` response header.  I found this particularly useful when dealing with a race condition in multiple AJAX requests, whereas one contained a very important session (cookie data) update and the other the session was not used, but Rails still sent back an updated cookie for the session.  The race condition could cause the updated session data from the important action to be overwritten from the one I didn't care about.